# PSD of modulated signal

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, signal-power

I know this question has been previously asked just saw it and tried to do myself but reaching an expression which is different from expression of PSD which I remember for modulated signal

Actual answer $$S(f-f_c)+S(f+f_c)$$

My answer $$S(f-f_c)+S(f+f_c)+2X(f-f_c)X(f+f_c)$$

where $S(f)$ is PSD of $x(t)$ and $X(f)$ is its Fourier transform while it is modulated by $\cos$ signal of $f_c$ frequency.

What I have followed is to find fourier transform of modulated signal and then square it.Where i have done wrong.

[image]

Comment: If you've got a different result than what is correct, you'll obviously need to give us your **full** derivation. How else are we supposed to find your mistake? My guess is you just forgot to take a critical step, but I can't know, and since, as you say, there's enough existing derivations out there that you can compare your own steps to, I'm not willing to spend time speculating.

Comment: If $X(f)$ is a low-pass function (say  to 10 kHz(and $f_c$ a high-frequency carrier signal (say 1MHz), can you tell me a specific value of $f$ for which $X(f-f_c)X(f+f_c)$ is  nonzero?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate I know that this term will be zero for low pass input (fc>W) but I no where mentioned x(t) is low pass.

Comment: Congratulations. And while we are nitpicking about the details of what you wrote, let me remind you that the PSD is _not_ the _square_ of the Fourier transform of the signal.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Iconfused ESD with PSD sorry,Then how to I derive PSD of modulated signal its auto-correlation is coming R(a)cos(vt)cos(v(t+a)) where R(a) is auto-correlation of x(t) and v is modulating carrier frequency.

Answer (score 3):

If $x(t)$ is a finite-energy signal with Fourier transform $X(f)$, then $x(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ is also a finite-energy signal with Fourier transform $\left.\left.\frac 12 \right[X(f-f_c) + X(f+f_c)\right]$. This is just the *modulation theorem* of Fourier transform theory.

The *energy spectral density* of $x(t)$ is $S_x(f) = |X(f)|^2$ while the energy spectral density of $y(t) = x(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ is
\begin{align}S_y(f) &= \bigg|\left.\left.\frac 12 \right[X(f-f_c) + X(f+f_c)\right]\bigg|^2\\
&= \left.\left.\frac 14 \right[ |X(f-f_c)|^2 + |X(f+f_c)|^2 + 2\Re\big(X(f-f_c)X^*(f+f_c)\big)\right]\\
&= \left.\left.\frac 14 \right[S_x(f-f_c)+S_x(f+f_c)+2\Re\big(X(f-f_c)X^*(f+f_c)\big)\right]\tag{1} 
\end{align}
which has a vague resemblance to what the OP wrote.  Now, if $x(t)$ is a low-pass signal with bandwidth $W$ Hz and $W < f_c$, then $X(f-f_c)$ occupies the frequency band from $f_c-W > 0$ to $f_c+W$ while $X(f+f_c)$ occupies the frequency band from $-f_c-W$ to $-f_c+W < 0$. We see that there is no value of $f$ for which $X(f-f_c)$ and $X(f+f_c)$ both are nonzero, and thus $X(f-f_c)X^*(f+f_c)$ equals $0$ for all $f$. We are left with
\begin{align}
S_y(f) &= \left.\left.\frac 14 \right[S_x(f-f_c)+S_x(f+f_c)\right]\\
&= \left.\left.\frac 14\right[|X(f-f_c)|^2+|X(f+f_c)|^2\right].\tag{2}\end{align} 
But when $f_c$ is smaller than $W$, then, as the OP peevishly has informed us all that he has placed no restrictions on the value of $f_c$, he must learn to live with the more complicated $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot the low-pass filtering step applied after modulation with a carrier that other derivations do.

Comment: There is no low-pass filtering after modulation in any derivation that I have seen.

Comment: Then you simply get the intermodulation products of carrier and LO frequency at both the difference and sum frequency – no way around that with a mixer.

Comment: In _modulation_ there is _no_ local oscillator and a separate carrier frequency to create a sum and difference frequency. Alternatively, the local oscillator is at _zero_ frequency and so the sum and difference frequencies are $f_c$ and $-f_c$, i.e. the spectrum moves to be centered at $\pm f_c$, where $f_c$ is the carrier frequency.